# How can I use a Ruby Gem file local to my project as opposed to a gem installed on the system?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I have the SASS gem installed on my system (v3.3.8), but I have a project that requires v3.2.19). I also have a situation where there is a conflict on the system with v3.2.19 exsiting (Codekit won't compile SASS if any older versions of a gem are installed).

I used Bundler to install a copy of the required gems in a folder local to my project:

`my_project/src/vendor/bundle/ruby/...`

How can I force my project to use the ruby gems in the local folder for my grunt tasks, instead of those installed globally on my system?

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"    

gem 'autoprefixer-rails', ">=1.2.0.20140609"
gem 'breakpoint', ">=2.0.7"
gem 'compass', ">=0.12.6"
gem 'sass', ">=3.2.19"
gem 'singularitygs', ">=1.1.2"
```

Comment: Run `bundle install` in your project directory (where the `Gemfile` is located) to install the gems and launch executables with `bundle exec ...`, e.g. `bundle exec compass compile`

Comment: I already ran `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`. I'm trying to use  `:path =>` to point to these files instead of system files, but regardless of where I look in the `vendor/bundle` folder I keep getting an error message: `Could not find gem 'compass (>= 0.12.6) ruby' in source at vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache.
Source does not contain any versions of 'compass (>= 0.12.6) ruby'`. http://philsinatra.net/_ex/ss.png

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec` was the correct command.